# How to call push() function from firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get a unique key from the push function but whenever I call it I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: postsRef.push is not a function at HTMLFormElement.
These are my imports:

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.6/firebase-app.js";
import { getDatabase, set, ref, update, onValue, remove, push } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.6/firebase-database.js";
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged, signOut } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.6/firebase-auth.js";
```

And these are the lines that I use to call the push function:

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getDatabase(app);
const postsRef = ref(db, 'devices/');
const newPostRef = postsRef.push();
```

I hope you guys can help me, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push` is nowadays a top-level function, and no longer a method in a reference.

Since you're already importing `push`, you can use it as:

```
const newPostRef = push(postsRef);
```

The change is very mechanical here: changing from `object.operation()` to `operation(object)`, which is a common pattern when moving over from older Firebase SDK to v9 and above.

Comment: That solved it, thank you so much!